Installer Hadoop sur un cluster DOCKER
Le projet DS du module BIG DATA consiste à :

Installer Hadoop sur un cluster DOCKER composé au minimum de
machines, un NameNode et deux dataNodes.
Le rendu dans cette partie est un manuel d’installation détaillé.
Analyse de fichier de données purchases.txt déployé dans le cluser
docker hadoop. Cette analyse consiste à écrire des procédures mapper et
reducer en python pour répondre aux questions suivantes :
a. Quel est le chiffre d’affaire total par item ?
b. Quel est l’item le plus vendu selon le chiffre d’affaire ?
c. Quelle est la moyenne de vente par store ?
d. Quel est l’item le plus vendu pour chaque store ?
Pour chacune de ces questions, lancer la commande Hadoop jar en
spécifiant ses différents paramètres ainsi que son résultat.
Le rendu est les procédures mapper.py et réducer.py ainsi que les
différentes commandes hadoop permettant de répondre à ces
questions.
Choisir un dataset du site kaggle.com appartenant à domaine tel que : la
santé, finance, sport, jeux , ect
a. Définir de mesures de performance ( KPI) liées au domaine de
dataset.
b. Ecrire des requête en SPARK SQL permettant de calculer les KPIs
définies.
Le rendu est la description des KPIs définis, les requête SPARK SQL et
les résultats obtenus ( une partie du résultat)

solutin detaille Le rendu dans cette partie est un manuel d’installation détaillé

StackOverflow is an English language forum, please ask your question in English: https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions
